# Is there any way to use a C# library in a Qt/C++ project?

Tags: c#, c++, qt

I'm trying to use the [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/) library in a Qt/C++ project. Is this possible? I have successfully used this library to get the CPU temperatures in C#.

Comment: Qt supports COM well, use the [ComVisible] attribute in your C# code.

Comment: After reading some articles, i discovered that i need to use a QAxObject to interact with COM objects. I've used this library to read and write an Excel document. I'm in the right way to use a OpenHardwareMonitor library in a Qt project? If yes, how to access the OpenHardwareMonitor functions in Qt?

Comment: I am currently doing something similar, when I have the time: converting the openhardwaremonitor code to being a DLL that way it is callable from just about anywhere.  Doing the same with either the whole codebase or just the functions that you require, would allow you to use the DLL from C++ or virtually any other language in windows.